# Why am I getting this error in a basic Rails+Ember app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to do a simple CRUD app using Ember + Rails and I'm getting the following error when trying to go to the `/workouts` route.

```
Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember.js?body=1:415
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
    var m = meta(this), proto = m.proto;
    m.proto = this;
    if (initMixins) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var mixins = initMixins;
      initMixins = null;
      this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
    }
    if (initProperties) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var props = initProperties;
      initProperties = null;

      var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

      for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
        var properties = props[i];

        Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

        for (var keyName in properties) {
          if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

          var value = properties[keyName],
              IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

          if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
            var bindings = m.bindings;
            if (!bindings) {
              bindings = m.bindings = {};
            } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
              bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
            }
            bindings[keyName] = value;
          }

          var desc = m.descs[keyName];

          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));
          Ember.assert("`actions` must be provided at extend time, not at create time, when Ember.ActionHandler is used (i.e. views, controllers & routes).", !((keyName === 'actions') && Ember.ActionHandler.detect(this)));

          if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
            var baseValue = this[keyName];

            if (baseValue) {
              if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
                value = baseValue.concat(value);
              } else {
                value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
              }
            } else {
              value = Ember.makeArray(value);
            }
          }

          if (desc) {
            desc.set(this, keyName, value);
          } else {
            if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
              this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
            } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
              Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
            } else {
              this[keyName] = value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    finishPartial(this, m);
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    m.proto = proto;
    finishChains(this);
    sendEvent(this, "init");
  } has no method 'find'
```

My code is located here: https://github.com/ecl1pse/ember-workouts

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Upon further investigation I believe the culprit is

```
EmberWorkouts.WorkoutsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: -> EmberWorkouts.Workout.find()
```

This doesn't actually return anything. How do I debug from there?

If I replace that with this

```
EmberWorkouts.WorkoutsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> [{title: 'hi'}, {title: 'damn'}]
```

The view actually renders content.

How do I get the model to collect from Rails properly?

Comment: What is your error message?, line number?

Comment: That is my error message. It appears that my `EmberWorkouts.WorkoutsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: -> EmberWorkouts.Workout.find()
` is broken. That doesn't actually do anything. How do I debug from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data's interface has changed a little with the current release:

1. You can clear out the `store.js` file entirely. Ember Data will automatically set up a data store for you using the REST Adapter (unless you tell it otherwise).
2. Use `model: -> @store.find('workout')` instead.

I tested this with your app and it works.

If you haven't read through the [Ember Data Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/) in the last week or two (it's changed a lot), I would spend a few minutes on it.

Comment: I get this: `Assertion failed: You must include an id in a hash passed to push` - thanks though. Good tip. I'll try to figure it out...

Comment: I still can't figure it out. Updated repo to reflect my hurdle. Any idea? @dylan

Comment: What's the solution? Saying you might have found a solution and not posting it is quite possibly the most annoying thing you can do on this site.

Comment: Not sure if anyone else is having the `You must include an 'id' in a hash passed to push` issue, but for me the fix was to pass along an id with the JSON response from the serializer. Also, the ember model can't have an id property specified.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this error (as of ember-data 1.0.0.beta.6) for me was to make sure that the JSON returned from the server included an "id" field for each model, BUT not to explicitly declare the id when setting up the Ember DS.Model.

jbuilder template:

```
json.scans do
  json.array! @scans do |scan|
    json.id scan.id # This prop has to be there
    json.name scan.name
  end
end
```

Ember model:

```
EmberApp.Scan = DS.Model.extend(
  // Don't include the id prop here
  name: DS.attr("string")
)
```